# Regex to ignore alphanumeric characters in a string

Tags: regex

I've a regex which currently checks for a member number present in a string with memberNo between 6 and 9 in length

```
(?<memberNo>[0-9]{6,9})
```

What i need is if i get the input `123a456` that the regex ignores any alphanumeric characters in where the contiguous int values between 6 and 9 are present.

For example these should all match

```
123456
a123456
123a456
12345a6
```

etc

Comment: Why not remove all non-digits first and then match

Comment: Add an optional letter matching pattern, `(?<memberNo>(?:[a-zA-Z]?[0-9]){6,9})` or `(?<memberNo>(?:[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]){6,9})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow any letter between the digits using

```js
(?<memberNo>(?:[a-zA-Z]?[0-9]){6,9})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UG14uz/1).

*Details*

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[a-zA-Z]?` - one or zero ASCII letters
  - `[0-9]` - a single ASCII digits
- `){6,9}` - end of the group, repeat six to nine times.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D)%7B6%2C9%7D):

[image]

Comment: (?<memberNo>(?:[a-zA-Z]*?[0-9]){6,9}) was what i ended up using but this got me really close to what i needed thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems

```
(?<memberNo>[0-9a-z]{6,9})
```

would match all your target strings. However, this pattern allows strings without a numeric character.

To mandate one or more numeric characters, [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) could be used.

```
(?<memberNo>(?=.*[0-9])[1-9a-z]{6,9})
```

The `(?=.*[0-9])` part is positive lookahead.

You can test this regex here https://regexr.com/5oua2